# Get axis-x position inside scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollto, jquery-scrollable

I have a scrollable div which overflow is hidden. I am using [this](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plug-in to scroll the div. How can I detect the axis x position with jquery (or maybe with this plug-in) so if there is nothing to scroll on left, I would be able to hide the left arrow, and show it again when the axis has moved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [`scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollLeft) property.

It can be accessed like an attribute in jQuery.

```
var scrollLeft = $('element').attr('scrollLeft');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5trza/).

To determine if the user has scrolled all the way to the left, check for `(scrollLeft == 0)`.

To see if they have scrolled all the way to the right, you should be able to do `(scrollLeft == element.attr('scrollWidth') - element.width())`.